# Access Grails Fixture

Tags: grails, testing, groovy, fixtures, spock

I have some fixtures I am creating in my Grails integrations specs.  What I would like to do is somehow retrieve said fixture without having to tie it to a "findBy" method and some property on the object.  Let me explain, my fixture is listed like so.

```
fixture {
    superBiscuitMaker(BiscuitMaker,
            firstName: "ButterMe"
            lastName: "Biscuits"
     )
}
```

And then in my integration test, when I want to access "superBiscuitMaker", I would do something like this.

```
def maker = BiscuitMaker.findByFirstName("ButterMe")
```

That seems a little redundant since I have already labeled the BiscuitMaker(SuperBiscuitMaker) in question in my fixture.  I've read the documentation, but its kind of thin, and it refers to version 1.0.2 and I am using 1.2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to maintain hold of the return object by the fixture holder.

```
    class SomeControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    ...
    def fixtures
    def setup() {
        String[] fixturesList = ["biscuits/BiscuitMakers","something/Else"]
        fixtures = fixtureLoader.load(fixturesList)
    }

    void "Update biscuit maker"(){
        when:
        def bMaker = fixtures.superBiscuitMaker
    }
```